# How did Henry Kater measure distances down one part in $10^5$?

Tags: acceleration, history, distance, experimental-technique, metrology

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kater%27s_pendulum#Experimental_procedure) that in 1817, Henry Kater was able to measure distances accurately enough to get at least five significant figures in a measurement of $g,$ suggesting that he could measure a distances on the order of one meter to an accuracy of one hundredth of a millimeter. Indeed, Wikipedia claims he made this measurement to an accuracy of $2.5 \;\mathrm{\mu m}.$

This would be an absolute distance measurement, not detecting changes in distance (as one would do with an interferometer). How did Kater achieve this accuracy?

Comment: The Wiki article says that he did this with a "microscope comparator", but I have no idea what that is or how it works.

Comment: Here's [Kater's article from 1818](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rstl.1818.0006), though it may be paywalled for some/most people.  The description of the calibration method starts on p. 49.

Comment: [Kater’s paper is available at archive.org](https://ia600304.us.archive.org/20/items/philtrans08020183/08020183.pdf)